# Query method to find from a list

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to get the object from `communication` table that has Integer x in `appointment_type_ids`. Can I write a finder method for that?

Communication.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "communication")
public class Communication{


   
    @Column("id")
    private Long id;

    @Column("name")
    private String name;

    @Column("appointment_type_ids")
    private ArrayList<Integer> appointmentTypeIds;

}
```

I tried putting `List<Communication> findByAppointmentTypeIdsContaining(Integer integer);` in the repository, as suggested by @João Dias.
Following is the error log I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.CommunicationRepository.findByAppointmentTypeIdsContaining(java.lang.Integer)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.CommunicationRepository.findByAppointmentTypeIdsContaining(java.lang.Integer)! unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.CommunicationRepository.findByAppointmentTypeIdsContaining(java.lang.Integer)! unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1056) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.CommunicationRepository.findByAppointmentTypeIdsContaining(java.lang.Integer)! unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilderImpl.isMember(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:1343) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.isMember(JpaQueryCreator.java:331) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:290) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:124) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:59) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:217) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:348) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

In your repository for `Communication` try adding the following method:

```java
List<Communication> findByAppointmentTypeIdsContaining(Integer appointmentTypeId);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error -

```unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]```

Comment: I've updated my answer. I guess that the query will return a list of `Communication`.

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: Can you please try replacing `private ArrayList<Integer> appointmentTypeIds;` with `private List<Integer> appointmentTypeIds;`? You should always use Interfaces (`List`) instead of concrete implementions (`ArrayList`).

Comment: Tried that too, gives the same exceptions.

Comment: Can you provide the complete logs ?

Comment: @NKShukla I added it in the post